# Vungle plug-in for Corona sdk playing ad over my background music?

Tags: audio, coronasdk, ads

Hi i am implementing vungle using the plugin for corona sdk.

The video shows fine but the advert plays over the top of my background music / sound.

I have tried calling audio.pause and audio.setVolume(0) before the advert is shown but that doesn't work, even if i call audio pause or setvolume and then show the ad wih a second delay.

The audio is paused but then resumes when the advert plays one second later.

E-mailed vungle but haven't had a reply.. I saw a post on the dev forums about it but it had no replies so i know other people have had the same problem just wondered if anyone has a solution?

Thanks!